# Karma - Jasmine Disconnected timeout

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-chrome-launcher

I have write the test cases using Karma and Jasmine. Test cases can't execute the below error is thrown.

[image]

Karma.js

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
        browserDisconnectTimeout: 20000,
        browserDisconnectTolerance: 0,
        browserNoActivityTimeout: 100000,

        browsers: ['ChromeHeadless_without_security'],
        customLaunchers: {
            ChromeHeadless_without_security: {
                base: 'ChromeHeadless',
                flags: [
                  '--disable-web-security',
                  '--use-fake-device-for-media-stream',
                  '--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream',
                  '--headless',
                  '--no-sandbox'
                ]
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Version:

```
"jasmine-core": "^2.8.0",
"karma": "^1.7.1",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0"
```

I tried below steps.

- I have increased `browserNoActivityTimeout` and `browserDisconnectTimeout` time. Issue still is there.
- I have upgraded to latest `Jasmine-core: 3.2.0`. But issue still present.
- I used ES6. So "PhontomJS/PhontomJS2" browsers doesn't supported.
- Downgrade/Upgrade the karma.

Note: The question already present but no solution on it. Thanks in advance.